# Counter strike 1.6 / condition zero - add Headshot, double kill,... sound

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

I really like the sound effect: headshot, double kill, multi kill,... some thing likes [this](https://youtu.be/9TMBYDDMquk). How can I add these effect to my Counter strike [1.6](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/CounterStrike/) or [condition zero](http://store.steampowered.com/app/80/CounterStrike_Condition_Zero/) game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server and a proper server mod for that. Typical for that is (or was) AMX Mod, which was abandoned long ago and is now succeeded by [AMX Mod X](http://www.amxmodx.org/).

With that installed you can install plugins like [Quake Sounds](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=638940?p=638940), which is exactly what you're asking for, just with different sound files (standard Quake sounds, which you can replace with your own ones).

Comment: Can I setup that for playing local? I mean just like a offline game.

Comment: If you're running it on your PC or local network you can just setup a password or bind it to your local IP. `sv_lan 1` in your config and the start parameter `-ip your.local.ip.address` should suffice for that.