# Counter strike 1.6 / condition zero - spawn immediately after death

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

Currently, when I play counter strike with bots, if my character dies, I'll have to wait until the match ends, maybe the reason is the mode of the map is defusing Bomb or rescuing hostages, so how can I setup the mode spawn immediately after death for my Counter strike [1.6](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/CounterStrike/) or [condition zero](http://store.steampowered.com/app/80/CounterStrike_Condition_Zero/) local game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324003/counter-strike-1-6-condition-zero-add-headshot-double-kill-sound) you need a server running [AMX Mod X](http://www.amxmodx.org/). With that done you can install [Deathmatch](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=390294).

If you want the server only available locally you have a few options:

- `sv_lan 1` in your server.cfg (indicates LAN mode)
- `sv_password xy` in your server.cfg (so only people who have the password can join)
- start parameter `-ip your.local.ip.address` so you can access the server only via that IP, which is only available in your local network
- Or just block the traffic on the port 27015 (but be sure to allow it again, if you want to play online again)