# Etymology of announcing headshots, double kills, multi kills, etc

Tags: counter-strike, first-person-shooter, quake, unreal-tournament-2004

I used to think that the origin of headshot, double kill, multi kill,... feature come from [cross fire](https://youtu.be/Uy3y9R5Xbe0) - [an online game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossFire_(video_game)). Thanks to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/324136/198960), I re-think about the origin of this feature.
I see that the mod called Quake sound is used to add this feature to Counter Strike. So I think that the origin maybe from the [quake game](https://youtu.be/JSb7q5WZMBw).
But after some research, I see that the headshot announcement may have come from [Unreal Tournament](https://youtu.be/MsOhttwr9Rg) instead.

What game first used announcements like headshot, double kill, and multi kill?

Comment: @Gigazelle: It's good that you improve my question, but I didn't mean to ask: "What are some other games that built upon this type of announcement system?", also you remove my 1.2.3 make the accepted answer out of place, you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 and 2 are easily answered in one answer:

The sounds are a combination of both, Unreal Tournament *and* Quake.

The kill streaks and headshot sounds are from UT and other sounds like Impressive, Holy Sh*t, etc are from Quake.

3 is too broad... There are too many mods out there doing equal stuff and they're all different. Basically every mod has sounds for:

- several kill streaks
- multikill (2 kills in 2 secs)
- headshot
- teamkill

...everything else may vary depending on the mod and game.

Comment: If it's too broad, is there a point to answering it?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer summing things up is still possible, just not listing everything as asked.

Comment: Sorry, 3 is just about the original system, Unreal Tournament & Quake.

Comment: @123iamking try to ask that in a separate question.. it's still not a good fit for this one.